# Derivative of a product of trig functions: $3\sin(x)\cot(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

I am having a lot of trouble understanding on how to find the derivative of $3\sin x\cot x$.

I end up with $-3\cos x/\sin^2 x$

Comment: Could you explain how you got there? [Adding context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) helps others understand your question better.

Comment: Isn't $3 \sin x \cot x = 3 \cos x$?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: I tried it again and I got -3sinx..

Comment: You're correct @Jose. It indeed is $-3\sin x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the product rule:

$$
(3\sin{x}\cot{x})'=\\
3(\sin{x})'\cot{x}+3\sin{x}(\cot{x})'=\\
3\cos{x}\cot{x}+3\sin{x}(-\csc^2{x})=\\
3\cos{x}\cot{x}-3\sin{x}\csc^2{x}=\\
3\cos{x}\frac{\cos{x}}{\sin{x}}-3\sin{x}\frac{1}{\sin^2{x}}=\\
3\frac{\cos^2{x}}{\sin{x}}-3\frac{1}{\sin{x}}=\\
3\frac{1}{{\sin{x}}}(\cos^2{x}-1)=\\
3\frac{1}{{\sin{x}}}(1-\sin^2{x}-1)=-3\sin{x}.
$$

A much simpler way to do this, as was mentioned in the comments section, is to notice that $3\sin{x}\cot{x}=3\sin{x}\frac{\cos{x}}{\sin{x}}=3\cos{x}$ which is trivial to differentiate:

$$
(3\cos{x})'=3(\cos{x})'=3(-\sin{x})=-3\sin{x}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

While Michael Rybkin's answer is correct, it is worth noting that the expression $3\sin(x)\cot(x)$ is not in the simplest form, and begs the use of a different approach. Recalling that

$$\cot(x) = \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$$

then

$$3\sin(x)\cot(x) = 3\sin(x) \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} = 3\cos(x)$$

Then the derivative is simply

$$\frac{d}{dx} 3\cos(x) = 3 \frac{d}{dx} \cos(x) = -3 \sin(x)$$

---

Of course, as noted in Michael's answer you can use the product rule,

$$\frac{d}{dx} f(x)g(x) = f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x)$$

and as shown there you still obtain the same answer.